# XMLHttpRequest onload destroys response when completed?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to package multiple xhr responses into a zip file **before download**

The problem is that when xhr.onload is done executing my reference to the response is destroyed.. seems like any deep copys I make within this function is destroyed as well.

Any workarounds?

```
                    var zip = new JSZip();
                    objs.each(function() {
                        var fileName = this.id;
                        var link = this.value;
                        xhr.open('GET', link, true);
                        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                        xhr.onload = function(e) {
                            zip.file(fileName, this.response);
                        };
                        xhr.send(null);
                    });
                    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (blob) {
                        saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
                    });
```

Comment: 1. You can call to response only once, but you trying to call to it several times. 2. You have to wait for all xhr.onload callbacks before generating zip. 3. You using same fileName for all entries.

Comment: You can't use the same XHR for multiple concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, Promises will shine:

```
function urlToPromise(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // create a new xhr each time
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr..... // set the other fields, call send(), etc
  };
}

var zip = new JSZip();
objs.each(function() {
  var fileName = this.id;
  var link = this.value;
  zip.file(fileName, urlToPromise(link));
});

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (blob) {
  saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
});
```

JSZip (v3+) supports array buffers but also promises of array buffers. `urlToPromise` creates a promise from an url by fetching it, and `zip.generateAsync` will internally wait for all ajax calls to resolve.